# How to convert a Step to Tasklet in spring-batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

How can I convert the following step to a tasklet?

```
@Bean
public Step set() {
    return stepBuilders.get("step")
      .<String, String>chunk(1)
      .reader(reader())
      .processor(processor())
      .writer(writer())
      .listener(logProcessListener())
      .faultTolerant()
      .skipLimit(10)
      .build();
}
```

Problem: there is no "TaskletBuilderFactory" or similar.

Comment: Please could you explain your intention? Is there no more need of reader/processor/writer etc. in this step?

Comment: I want to create a partitioned step, whereas the tasklet should consist of the step above.

Comment: Do you mean in a partitioned step where the slave step should be the step above?